# How to ask/reply questions in a work item in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: azure-devops

In Visual studio online, someone created a work item for me, but I didn't quite understand.
How to ask questions in a work item?

Comment: Add a comment to the history of the Work Item with your question, and assign it back to whoever assigned it to you?

Comment: I'm not sure so I'm asking :)

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this - my suggestion is but one way to do it, and it will likely depend on what type of internal workflow your team is using.

Comment: Brendan's answer is the standard way to do this, however please know that is difficult to get this information in any form of report or work item query. Once the question is answered, you should put that answer in the description field for easier viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our organization is currently looking into this as well to see the best way to do things.   You can open Boards, Work Items and then change the top left filter to Mentioned and it will show you all work items where you were mentioned...

But there is still the issue of knowing if the conversation is a feisty one and people replied multiple times on during the day whether or not it requires an answer from you.

While assigning cases back and forth between each other may feel silly, it's the best way to keep track of who the work item is waiting on.

"hey the ball is in your court, I'm waiting for an answer"

If you only want to let a person know they might be interested in that case the @mention is a great way to do it.

If person B requires an answer from someone else for something then they can assign it to them as well.  When the person answers the question they assign the case back to person A and boom there's your answer.

***The downside to assigning items to others is that it's really your task and will mess up how much work is assigned to you in your sprint.  If you are using that functionality to manage workload.***

How you do this in your organization really depends on if people are always on the ball looking at items when they are mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ask more information on a work item the best thing to do is @mention the person who created or assigned the work item to you in the discussion section. Go to the discussion control and type @ to bring up a search box to search for the person. See the image below:

[image: Reply to person]

When you save (save icon on top-right or ctrl+s) this notify that person you @mentioned with your update.